# How do i access the file(created by transformer and file outbound endpoint in mule) in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: mule

My mule flow inbound outbound points are as follows

```
<vm:inbound-endpoint address="vm://EDITransformation"
    exchange-pattern="request-response" transformer-refs="SmooksTransformer" />
<file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\smooks\test docs\out"
    responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Outgoing File"
    outputPattern="#[header:INBOUND:sourceFileName].xml">
</file:outbound-endpoint>
```

The source file is an edi file, availabe in classpath.

I call vm endpoint from java class using mule client

```
message = muleClient.send("vm://EDITransformation",in,Collections.singletonMap("sourceFileName", inputFileName));
```

An xml file is created at path D:\smooks\test docs\out, which is specified in file outbound endpoint.
I want to access that file in java class. How to set the file name in mule message to access it in java class?

One more question related to send() method of MuleClient:
Its trying to read the sourceFile from classpath. If i give source file name as D:\smooks\test docs\in\message1.edi, its trying to create output xml file at "D:\smooks\test docs\D:\smooks\test docs\out" and giving exception 
`Unable to create a canonical file for /D:/smooks/test docs/out//D:/smooks/test docs/in/BAPLIE1.edi.xml.`

How to specify file system location other than classpath?

Comment: Probably unrelated but make your life easier and do not use spaces in paths.

Comment: Removing spaces didn't work.

Comment: Mule's IOUtils.getResourceAsStream() method takes only the file name and searches for it in class path. Is there any other approach to create InputStream by specifying path and filename?

Comment: What about `new java.io.FileInputStream(...)`?